# ¿Cómo subir múltiples archivos desde el administrador de Django?

Tags: python, django

Quiero subir múltiples archivos en el administrador de Django, sin tener que colocar multiples campos de tipo `FileField`. El usuario puede ser capaz de administrar los archivos de manera sencilla; subir, eliminar o cambiar cada archivo de manera independiente pero subir varios de una sola vez.

**OBJETIVO FINAL**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO REALIZADO**

```
def case_upload_location(instance, filename):
    case_name = instance.name.lower().replace(" ", "-")
    file_name = filename.lower().replace(" ", "-")
    return "casos/{}/{}".format(case_name, file_name)


class Case(models.Model):
    # datos del caso
    name            = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=250)
    spoa            = models.CharField(max_length=21)
    observations    = models.TextField('Observaciones', null = True, blank = True)
    number_folder    = models.CharField('Numero de Carpeta', max_length=250)

    # alertas
    prescripcion    = models.DateField(default = timezone.now)
    caducidad       = models.DateField(default = timezone.now)
    cumplimiento    = models.DateField(default = timezone.now)


    # Multiples archivos a subir
    file1 = models.FileField('archivo 1', upload_to=case_upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
    file2 = models.FileField('archivo 2', upload_to=case_upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
    file3 = models.FileField('archivo 3', upload_to=case_upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
    file4 = models.FileField('archivo 4', upload_to=case_upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
```

Comment: te sugiero reivsar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529216/django-multiple-file-field

Comment: Te refieres a sólo fotos ?...

Comment: @JeanpierreRivas todo tipo de archivos, imágenes, pdf, archivos te text, entre otros

Comment: Para eso tienes que hacer varios inlines, pero uno diferente. Lo he intentado con fotos, pero con archivos he hecho solo de 1. No sé si funcione con files